# Depth-first search (DFS) for undirected graphs

Tags: scheme

I was looking at [this](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Graph/Undirected/Depth-first_search).

If I were just given a list that contained the number of edges (graph), pair of edges, a origin and a destination, how would I figure out if there is or isn't a path?

I have some idea, but just need a bit of help in terms of starting in scheme.

```
(is_it_a_path? '(4 ((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (2 4))) 1 4) ; returns true 

(is_it_a_path? '(3 ((1 2) (2 3) (3 1))) 2 3)       ; also returns true
```

In the following 4 is the number of vertices, (1 2)... and so are are the edges and 1 is the start and 4 is the end.  Basically from these you are looking at whether there is a path from 1 to 4 in the following defined graph. I hope that can clarify what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undirected graph path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402362/undirected-graph-path)

Comment: Yes Please ignore the other question....it wasn't explained properly....and I couldn't delete it.

Comment: But... you still haven't clarified the things I suggested you clarify in my answer to your other question? What's the data definition for graphs? Do you have purpose statements, contracts, or simpler/other examples? I still think my answer to that questions stands as a reasonable one to this question :).

Comment: I have edited the question...and put more clarifications... I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see John Clements's earlier response to look at How to Design Programs?  It has a [Chapter](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-35.html#node_chap_28) on how to design programs that deal with graphs.

As a meta-answer: the question you're asking, about how to get started on a problem that you're unfamiliar with, is the heart of the HtDP book.  Have you looked at it?  It's essentially an adaptation of Polya's How To Solve It, but tailored for writing computer programs rather than math proofs.  The [Second edition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) draft may be easier to read.