# Algorithm for finding undirected graph path

Tags: scheme, racket

What is a simple algorithm for finding a path in an undirected graph?

Comment: There is a cluster of graph-related Scheme questions coming into Stack Overflow in the past day or two.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426788/depth-first-search-dfs-for-undirected-graphs.  Is this a homework question?

Comment: yes it is but the other one is not my post

Comment: Strong recommendation: see: http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-35.html#node_chap_28, as well as http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-38.html

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to find whether a path exists is to implement [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). If you've done other kinds of recursive programming in Scheme, depth-first search will be pretty natural. The idea is that for each node, if it's the destination you're done; otherwise you recur on each of its children.

The only catch is that you need to keep track of nodes that have already been visited during your traversal so you can avoid visiting the same node twice; otherwise if you have a graph A <--> B <--> C and you're checking to see if A connects to C, you might loop infinitely going from A to B, then B to A, then A to B, and so on forever.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question relies on your graph representation.  The typical algorithm is Dijkstra's algorithm (note that this algorithm will find the shortest path, but that works fine).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

It's a fairly simple algorithm to implement, and among the path finding algorithms probably the most intuitive.

Comment: The function i have to write is just supposed to return either true or false if there is a path or not. Furthermore, the graph is defined as

is_path? '(3 ((1 2) (2 3)) 1 3) where 3 is the number of vertices, ((1 2) (2 3)) is the edges. The number of vertices is optional however. I looked at the Dijkstra's algorithm, however I am still completely lost. Further help would be appreciated.

Comment: The essence of Dijkstra's algorithm is that it uses a sort of transitive closure between the graph edges.  For example, in the first iteration you will see that if a -> b and b -> c, then a -> c, you will continue this, basically, until you find that there either is a path between two nodes in the graph, or you try all the different possible ways of going between the edges and find that there is no possible path.  bruce pointed you toward an implementation in Scheme which does this.